# automatic rounding off a during typecasting in c++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I did something like this

```
long double n;

cin >> n;

n = n * 10000;

long long int temp = (long long) n;
```

now when i try to print temp, then a problem occours in some test cases like 2.36

for 2.36 the value of temp should be 23600 but the value of temp comes out to be 23599

Pls someone help me out with this already got 4 wrong ans for this.. small problem

for simplification .. 
my code goes like this

```
int main()

{

int t;

for(scanf("%d", &t); t-- ;) {

    float n;
    scanf("%f", &n);
    n *= 10000;
    long int as = (long int) n;
   cout << "\nas : " << as << " n : " << n << endl;
    long  a, b;
    a = as;
    b = 10000;
    while(a%b != 0) {
        long  temp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    long  factor = b;
    cout << (10000/factor) << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

the aim of this program was something that .. i was given a number that can have at max 4 places after the decimal. that was the average score scored by a batsman so we had to find the minimum number of matches he should play to get that score

Comment: IEEE-754 Floating Point issue: Rounding error. (http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: `double` isn't an exact type. You don't *have* an exact value `2.36`.

Comment: And note that the cast isn't needed. The compiler will do this **conversion** without being told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the way floating-points are represented internally. You should **round** them off before performing truncation.

Doing a `floor(n+0.5)` or a `ceil(x-0.5)` would round the number correctly.

**EDIT:**

As your truncation step is a floor(..) operation in itself, you should just do `n = n * 10000 + 0.5` as @Mooing Duck stated.

([**Example**](http://ideone.com/vBnXO7))

Comment: The truncation is a floor, so really all he needs is a `+0.5` before the conversion and he's good to go.